# Mulitple row data consolidation in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have multiple rows of data corresponding to a single item in an ADX table. I need to consolidate the properties of a single item such that the output contains the latest value(by time) of the properties. The challenge is that, not all rows have updated values of each property. Another challenge is that, the operation needs to keep up with real-time data, so I'm looking for a light weight solution where around 10k changes need to be consolidated ever 20 seconds. So, expensive joins and bag operations may not be ideal.

For example, the data looks like below

```
INPUT TABLE CONTENT
time1   item1   prop1-0 null    prop3-0 null
time2   item1   null    null    prop3-1 null
time3   item1   prop1-1 null    null    prop4-0
time4   item1   prop1-2 prop2-0 prop3-2 null

EXPECTED PROCESSED OUTPUT
time4   item1   prop1-2 prop2-0 prop3-2 prop4-0
```

Answer (score 1):

does this meet your requirements?

I used substring to get what appeared to be major and minor versions, you could also use parse to do this cleaner.

Then I use summarize max(), then reconstituted the values with strcat.

```
datatable (ts:int, prop:string, a:string, b:string, c:string, d:string) [
1, 'item1', 'prop1-0', '', 'prop3-0', '',
2, 'item1', '', '', 'prop3-1', '',
3, 'item1', 'prop1-1', '', '', 'prop4-1',
4, 'item1', 'prop1-2', 'prop2-0', 'prop3-2', ''
]
| extend aMaj = substring(a, 4, 1), 
aMin = substring(a, 6, 1), 
bMaj = substring(b, 4, 1), 
bMin = substring(b, 6, 1), 
cMaj = substring(c, 4, 1), 
cMin = substring(c, 6, 1), 
dMaj = substring(d, 4, 1), 
dMin = substring(d, 6, 1)
| summarize ts = max(ts), max(aMaj), max(aMin), max(bMaj), max(bMin), max(cMaj), max(cMin), max(dMaj), max(dMin) by prop
| project ts, prop, strcat('prop', max_aMaj, '-', max_aMin), strcat('prop', max_bMaj, '-', max_bMin), strcat('prop', max_cMaj, '-', max_cMin), strcat('prop', max_dMaj, '-',         max_dMin)
```

returns

```
ts  prop    Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
4   item1   prop1-2 prop2-0 prop3-2 prop4-1
```